# ORA Scripts execution in a one shot

Tags: oracle

I need a suggestion.

The scenario is: I've to execute 20K ORA scripts via the SQLPLUS command window method in one Database.

Those scripts from IH DB.So,we are copying the contents from IH to HOSTE

THE Hosted DB version is very far behind from the IH DB.

I'm splitting into 5k scripts in a folder (5k * 4 = 20k), will generate a log file after 1 * 5k folder scripts executed. This is a long way.

Do suggest easy, unique & timeless consumption to execute 20K Oracle scripts.

Note: After execution, I've to report script errors to the manager if Q flushes stuck & then proceed further.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with examples of your scripts and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Where do these twenty thousand scripts come from? What do they do?

Comment: You can try this script with parameter -input_file=*.log https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/analyze_oracle_error_log.ps1

Comment: Please suggest an easy, unique & timeless consumption approach to execute 20K Oracle scripts.

Comment: You can try this script https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_export_dir_tables.ps1.  This script executes all sql files from the specified directory and creates separate csv files in a specified directory if there is a select in the scripts.

Comment: @DmitryDemin Thanks for the help.

We can implement the above method given by you.There is a challenge for Scripts/ packages /procedures / DDL /DML dependencies I can't proceed for further scripts until that gets solved by tech leads. In this scenario what we can do.

Comment: @saleem I can modify the script according to your requirements.

Comment: @saleem I create script https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_all_sql_dir.ps1. This script executes all sql files from the specified directory and creates one log.

Comment: @saleem I am glad that my script is useful to you.  if you have any suggestions you can email me.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I haven't tried yet. Surely I will send an e-mail if anything I needs regards to the coding.

Comment: @DmitryDemin Please reply to my email - anmol95115 one.